# Measure Dependency from different Projects (JDepend?)

Tags: java, eclipse, jdepend

So I have different projects in my Eclipse-Workspace, though they are all connected, meaning they call classes of each other. I know wanted to measure the dependency of some classes with JDepend. But the problem is, it only shows results matching the exact same package. But I want an analysis of all packages and classes, the class I want to analyse uses.

How can I accomplish this using JDepend4Eclipse or any other tool?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this tool http://trimatek.org/deep it measures the coupling between two Jars